# Is there a reason Google Reader drains this much battery?

Tags: battery-life, 4.1-jelly-bean, google-reader

It doesn't strike me as normal that Google Reader should drain more battery than even my screen. Is this a known bug, or is it a settings issue? I'm using 4.1.1

[image: Phone Print Screen]

Comment: Are you using the app a lot?

Comment: How frequently is it set to update?  Do you have it set to download content for offline viewing?  What phone are you using?  My guess is that it is frequently updating in the background and transmitting a lot of data.

Comment: 14+ hours on battery with 35% left? Doesn't seem like a problem to me.

Comment: Al: I'm almost certain that is a bug, the time wasn't reset when it started charging it again (not shown in the chart).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing [BetterBatteryStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats) or [GSam Battery Monitor Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm.pro).  Both apps can provide you granular data about how your phone's battery is being drained.  You know the power hog is Google Reader but these apps can help you determine if the app is killing the battery because it's using a ton of data or if it's initiating long or frequent wake-locks...

If I had to guess without any more info, I'd guess that Reader is updating in the background frequently and consuming a lot of data.